# is there a to a achieve this sort of staggered bubble layout with css, i'm unable to know where to even start from

Tags: css, vue.js, layout, grid

[image]

I'm trying to achieve this exact design but don't know how to approach it, whether to use grid or even flex. the content will also be dynamically rendered to I'm avoiding hard coding it

Comment: I don't see how a grid will work if the items are staggered.  Seems like a flexbox problem to me with use of `justify-content: center`.

You should post what you've tried and whether or not the layout needs to be flexible for an arbitrary number of bubbles.

Comment: @Pocketsand I've not started implmenting becuase i don't even know a good approach, also the content will be rendered dynamically so a bit hard for me

Comment: Try with flexbox.  Maybe you can figure out something clever using `:nth-child()` and left/right padding or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code below I posted html and css that you can use for styling similar to the image:

```css
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parentAll {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
/*    width: 1000px;*/
}

.parentAll:nth-child(2) {
    width: 100%;
}

.parentAll div {
    width: 220px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    height: 220px;
    font-size: 2rem;
    background-color: #135d21;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.parentAll div.active {
    color: #101000;
    background-color: #d79d25;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px)  {
    .parentAll div {
        width: 170px;
        height: 170px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>circles</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
   <section class="parentAll">
       <div>div1</div>
       <div class="active">div2</div>
       <div>div3</div>
       <div>div4</div>
    </section>
       
    <section class="parentAll">
       <div>div5</div>
       <div>div6</div>
       <div>div7</div>
       <div>div8</div>
       <div>div9</div>
    </section>
    
    <section class="parentAll">
       <div>div10</div>
       <div>div11</div>
       <div>div12</div>
       <div>div13</div>
   </section>
    
</body>
</html>
```

you could play with the "width" and "height" of ".parentAll div" to achieve the size that is suitable for you and in different screen sizes.

for rendering the content dynamically you can use javascript or vue or other options and that is not related to the style of circles.

Comment: thank you, this worked, however looping over a data with vue to achieve is a bt of a bottleneck for me

Comment: it is natural because usually javascript is more difficult than css. you can watch some "youtube" videos to learn that. for example this one is good in my opinion:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e4M2MvU5QuQ